# How do I make accounts system with Dust?

Tags: node.js, account, dust.js

I really hate php, so I've looked up for node.js render engines and found Dust, and it is really what I am looking for with postgres. However, I haven't found something similar to `$_SESSION` of php. Is there a way for this or I am picking the wrong tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dust.js is a templating language. PHP can be used as a templating language too but is also a full-blown programming language that is primarily used for creating Web applications. That's why it has a very easy way to initiate and store data about sessions – `$_SESSION`.

Dust.js, on the other hand, is only a templating language that can be compiled down to HTML. It is not a programming language and also doesn't provide a web server. If you want to store session data, you need a web framework like [Express](https://expressjs.com). It allows you to [use Dust.js as a templating language](https://github.com/swider/express-dust) **and** [store session data](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

***However***, I personally would – especially since you don't seem to have a special reason to use Dust.js above other templating languages, recommend trying out [Pug.js](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html). It's – contrary to Dust.js – actively maintained, used by a **lot** of developers, has a very nice syntax and can be activated in Express with [just one line of code](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-template-engines.html).

#### *Edit:* `express-session` example usage

```
const express = require('express')
const session = require('express-session')

const app = express()

app.use(session({
  secret: 'keyboard cat',
  resave: false,
  // This option automatically initiates a session for every visitor
  saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  if (!req.session.views) req.session.views = 0
  req.session.views++
  res.send(`You viewed this page ${req.session.views} times`)
})
```

Comment: I will definetely take a look at Pug.js, but can I store data there with `express-session`? EDIT: I think it does :P

Comment: Also, `express-session` lacks examples, can you give me one?

Comment: @TalhaTalipAçıkgöz I've added a simple example.